# postfix what is this, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1

Tags: postfix, settings

When I got a `451 4.3.5 Server configuration` problem, I was informed to delete these settings from postfix configuration:

```
check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777,
check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
```

What are those and are those important? I'm only sending emails.

I deleted these lines from my postfix and server configuration error disappeared. This was my original postfix setting of this part where `check_policy` is located:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unlisted_recipient, permit_mynetworks,check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

And this is part of my current iredapd.log:

```
2015-06-30 11:12:29 INFO [157.56.122.54] END-OF-MESSAGE,  -> bounce@sample.com, DUNNO
2015-06-30 11:12:29 INFO [137.56.142.67] END-OF-MESSAGE,  -> 
bounce@sample.com, DUNNO
2015-06-30 11:12:30 INFO [96.231.115.34] END-OF-MESSAGE,  -> bounce@sample.com, DUNNO
2015-06-30 11:12:30 INFO [72.80.169.254] END-OF-MESSAGE,  -> bounce@sample.com, DUNNO
2015-06-30 11:12:31 INFO [117.55.334.94] END-OF-MESSAGE,  -> bounce@sample.com, DUNNO
2015-06-30 11:12:31 INFO [137.65.234.138] END-OF-MESSAGE,  -> bounce@sample.com, DUNNO
2015-06-30 11:12:31 INFO [117.56.112.67] END-OF-MESSAGE,  -> bounce@sample.com, DUNNO
```

Which part of `/var/log/maillog` should I check to know the message has been sent successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Your Postfix is configured to use [external policy services](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html), among them [iRedAPD](https://bitbucket.org/zhb/iredapd). By removing the configuration you disable policy checking -- probably not what you intend to do.

The mail delivery status is logged in maillog, you can find it via queue ID.